# WinError 10061 Running Selenium+Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, urllib

I have a Python GUI application that uses Selenium and Chromedriver to crawl sites, interact with elements, download files, etc. The application has been packaged as a standalone .exe (produced using PyInstaller) and has performed well in tests across a few different Windows and Mac machines. However, on one machine it is producing WinError 10061, screenshot below:

[image: WinError 10061]

A few other details:

- The Web Crawler application appears to work fine and hit all targets when run in headless mode
- Directly ahead of this error, the crawler successfully 1) opened the Chromedriver browser (outside of headless mode, so the webpage was visible) 2) accessed the start URL and performed automated tasks on the page (I.e., filling out and completing a login page, clicking 'Submit' button, refreshing page). It's only when accessing subsequent URLs that the Chromedriver quits and produces this error. I'm not sure why it be able to successfully initiate the browser, get the start URL and perform tasks, but fails upon getting another URL on the same site
- The URL it fails upon is `https://econtent.hogrefe.com/toc/prx/current`, but the error has been seen on completely different sites that similarly do not use the headless browser.

Any ideas as to what's happening here?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the error stacktrace.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium apologies if I'm missing something, is this info not clear in the screenshot? Error is traced back to webdriver's `get` function

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try get a version with formatted text (this is the screenshot the person trying to run the code sent me - I haven't been able to reproduce the error on my own).